# Constantly dying workers Flask-SocketIO + uWSGI

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, flask-socketio, python-3.8

I'm trying to implement sockets usage in my flask project and followed by flask-socketio documentation I had made it run perfectly with gunicorn, but found myself unable to make it work using uwsgi. It seems like it should be working even with the simplest app and settings but it just keeps killing the workers whatever configuration I try to use. Here's an example of an environment and code I have:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask    
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'extremelysecret'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

pip freeze:

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SocketIO==4.3.0
gevent==20.5.0
greenlet==0.4.15
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
python-engineio==3.12.1
python-socketio==4.5.1
six==1.15.0
uWSGI==2.0.18
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Running with an example from documentation:

```
uwsgi --http :5000 --gevent 1000 --http-websockets --master --wsgi-file app.py --callable app
```

Output:

```
your processes number limit is 63299
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
- async cores set to 10 - fd table size: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :5008 fd 4
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:39875 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 3.8.0 (default, Jan  9 2020, 23:03:43)  [GCC 7.4.0]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55899af6a860
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 501072 bytes (489 KB) for 20 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking+async ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x55899af6a860 pid: 22479 
(default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 22479)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 22481, cores: 10)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 22482, cores: 10)
*** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x558998a7f860] ***
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 22483)
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 22481) died :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 22484)
DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 22482) died :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 22485)
*** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x558998a7f860] ***
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 22484) died :( trying respawn ...
```

So far I've tried:

> ```
> - playing with uwsgi parameters;
> - using different app configurations in app.py;
> - using couple different versions of python;
> - figuring out is everything installed properly;
> ```

And still, my guess is that I miss something obvious here. Thanks in advance for pointing me on that.

Comment: Are you sure the uwsgi command that you showed matches the logs? In the log you have two worker processes. Where is that setting if not in the start up command? Do you also have a config file?

Comment: Hi @alexxmagpie, Any luck on this? I keep getting the same issue with uWSGI and gevent .The worker keeps spawning and dying..